# Adding domain specifics to regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a current regex that I use to extract all links from a txt file.

What I need to add to it is to extract all urls ONLY where twitter is in the domain.

Can anyone quickly help out with what I need to modify in this regex to accomplish this?

Thanks

```
$regex = '/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i';
```

There is also this regex that I could use but it would still need the same addition made to it.

```
#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you really need it to match `ftp://` and `file://`? And does the domain have to be twitter.com and its subdomains or do you want `1twitter123.org` to match too? Sometimes it helps if you explain what you are actually trying to do instead of just posting your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match('%https?://(?:www\.)?twitter\.com[^\s]*%i', $subject, $regs)
```

---

**Regex Explanation:**

```
https?://(?:www\.)?twitter\.com[^\s]*

Options: Case insensitive

Match the character string “http” literally (case insensitive) «http»
Match the character “s” literally (case insensitive) «s?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
Match the character string “://” literally «://»
Match the regular expression below «(?:www\.)?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   Match the character string “www” literally (case insensitive) «www»
   Match the character “.” literally «\.»
Match the character string “twitter” literally (case insensitive) «twitter»
Match the character “.” literally «\.»
Match the character string “com” literally (case insensitive) «com»
Match a single character that is NOT a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) «[^\s]*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
```

---

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xM1cS9/1)

Comment: Oh one possible edit, add .* to the end so it matches the entire url, not just the twitter bit

Comment: @Brett I was doing that while you commented, tks

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work

```
\b((https?|ftp|file):\/\/twitter\.com[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])
```

I just ran it on the following text

```
this is my test string http://www.google.com/sdfsdf.php https://twitter.com/mylink
```

Comment: Use Pedro's below it's much cleaner